# Two nested for loops involving itertools don't produce the permutations of the outer loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I have the following bit of code:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = range(6)
p = itertools.permutations(a)
p2 = itertools.product(b,b,b,b,b)

for pos in p:
    for shift in p2:
        print(pos,shift)
```

which prints out:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (0, 0, 0, 0, 4)
...
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) (5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

The outer loop is executed only once. If I do

```
for pos in p:
    print(pos)
```

the loop executes just fine:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 4, 3)
...
(4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Why is this happening, and how do I make the two nested for loops work? Note that I have tried looping over `list(p)` instead of just `p` and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: After you have looped through the inner loop once, that iterator is spent. You can't loop through `p2` twice. If you want to do this you need to make a new iterator after each outer loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for why the code isn't operating as you expect it to is the same reason as why this wouldn't work:

```
p = iter(range(6))
p2 = iter(range(6))

for pos in p:
    for shift in p2:
        print(pos,shift)
```

`itertools.product` returns an iterator that can only be consumed once. The first time you loop through `p2` you have consumed all of the values, and subsequent iterations of the outer loop essentially become a no-op.

You need to store the iterator output to a container that can be iterated over multiple times, or call `itertools.product` multiple times to reconstruct as necessary.

```
import itertools

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = range(6)
p = itertools.permutations(a)
p2 = list(itertools.product(b,b,b,b,b))

for pos in p:
    for shift in p2:
        print(pos,shift)
```

Or

```
import itertools

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = range(6)
p = itertools.permutations(a)

for pos in p:
    p2 = itertools.product(b,b,b,b,b)
    for shift in p2:
        print(pos,shift)
```

*Note: In reality, the `permutations` and `product` methods are actually constructor calls to generate operation specific classes, however, they do implement the iterator interface so I'm just calling them that!*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. One thing confuses me a bit: when I loop through `p2`, why do I consume `p`? Shouldn't the output have been all the values of `p` being paired with the last value of `p2`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate `p` is in the outer loop. You choose the first value of `p` and then evaluate everything in `p2`. Because `p2` is empty on subsequent values of `p`, the nested for-loop never enters its code block. Consider the following `for i in range(0): print("Somethings fishy", i)`

Comment: @sodiumnitrate looping through `p2` does not consume `p`, but your `p2` is exhausted on the *first* iteration of `p`. The body of the inner loop is never entered after that.